# How to create a delay between button click (to prevent button spamming)

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a java program that involves a button that gives a bunch of problems. I'm wondering how can I create a delay between the times a user can click a button (to prevent button spamming). Here is what I tried.

```
public void ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Thread DelayTHREAD = new Delay();
    if(DelayTHREAD.isAlive()) {
        /*do nothing*/
    }
    else {
        /*some other code*/
        DelayTHREAD.start();
    }
}
public static class Delay extends Thread /*Prevents user from spamming buttons*/ {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000); /*sleeps for the desired delay time*/
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
        }
    }
}
```

OK so here is the problem, it doesn't matter whether or not the delay thread is started or not, the program still goes on and continues to perform the action performed as if the delay thread never even existed.

Someone please tell me how can I create a delay, so that a user cannot spam button in a program? Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might just create a little method that disables the button for a period of time after the user clicks on it, and then enables it afterward, like so:

```
static void disable(final AbstractButton b, final long ms) {
    b.setEnabled(false);
    new SwingWorker() {
        @Override protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
            return null;
        }
        @Override protected void done() {
            b.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Then call it from your actionPerformed method like this:

```
disable(button, 5000);
```

Just make sure you call it from the EDT.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer more? It is rather too localized.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `SwingTimer` to inject a delay between the button click and the activation of the associated action....

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
/*...*/
private Timer attackTimer;
/*...*/

attackTimer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // Do attack...
    }
});
attackTimer.setRepeats(false);

/*...*/

public void ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Restart the timer each time the button is clicked...
    // In fact, I would disable the button here and re-enable it
    // in the timer actionPerformed method...
    attackTimer.restart();
}
```